# Extending XamlCompiler to deserialize string to collection

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

In the context of a Universal Windows application, I have the following class (located in .NET Standard library):

```
public class Store
{
     ICollection<string> Products { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

and the following XAML

```
<DataContext>
     <local:Store Products="Banana, Orange, Lemmon">
<DataContext>
```

Evidently, when I compile it, the **XamlCompiler** complaints because it doesn't know how to convert a string into a ICollection

My question is:

Is there a way to extend the **XamlCompiler** to make it learn **how to convert comma-separated string into `ICollection<string>`**?

I've seen there is a compile-time attribute:
`CreateFromStringAttribute`, but I cannot use in my `Store` class because it's located in a .NET Standard class library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the UWP XamlCompiler supports only the CreateFromStringAttribute.

In WPF you would use the TypeConverterAttribute and a TypeConverter to convert the string to the collection. But that TypeConverterAttribute is ignored by UWP's XamlCompiler. A reason for this is because UWP relies on the WinRT API, and things like type conversion need to work without .NET. .NET and C# is just one way to build UWP apps.

I looked already into that conversion more detailed when I created the XAML: Getting Started course for Pluralsight that has an "Understanding XAML Type Conversion" module (see here https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/xaml-getting-started). There I show both ways, CreateFromStringAttribute and TypeConverterAttribute.

You can read more about why UWP uses another attribute here in Tim's post: https://timheuer.com/blog/implement-type-converter-uwp-winrt-windows-10-xaml/

What does that mean for you?

You can't create only a .NET Standard class library. Or in other words, you can't target only .NET Standard if you want to have that conversion in the library. You have to multi-target and UWP needs to be a target, else you don't get the CreateFromStringAttribute, and currently there's no other way to hook into that conversion.

I hope this helps,
Thomas